# Why do some vaccines require periodical shot updates while others don't?

Tags: vaccination

I was wondering, what is the reason some vaccines provide a lifelong immunity against a disease while others require periodical shots to keep one immunised against a disease.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE, user18849! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You may improve your question to better comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!